# how to display TabBar on all shell child pages in single page app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I want to create a single page application using Shell where each page contains a titlebar that looks like [Back] [Title] [Settings].

If I have this sequence of pages [Login] -> [Home] -> [Settings]  I want when I navigate between them to see the same titlebar on each.

I have a ControlTemplate setup for the titlebar and I add it to each of the xaml pages like this: =

```
<Shell.TitleView>
        <TemplatedView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TopBar}" />
</Shell.TitleView>
```

I have the Login and Home pages registerd as routes in the Shell constructor.

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SettingsPage), typeof(SettingsPage));
}
```

In the Shell.xaml I have the login page registered like this: -

```
   <TabBar>
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}" Route="LoginPage" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

When I run the app the TitleView is displayed on the login page. I then click the button to login and I'm taken to the home page but the TitleView is missing. If navigate to the Settings page by clicking on the TitleView icon it is also missing.

Both settings page and Home page have `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"` set.

I'm navigating like this from Commands

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Views.SettingsPage)}");
```

Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer is don't add  `Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"` by mistake to pages you are navigating to. Doh!